# mismatched types ^ expected `Result<R, i32>`, found `Result<(Vec<i32>, u64), i32>`

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I want to write a fn to watch consul service , but my code complain error,  how to fix my code ?  and how to understand the right way?

tip:  fn watch_service<F, R>(&self, callback: F) where F: FnMut(Result<R, i32>) must not be change .

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/test.rs:12:18
   |
10 |     fn watch_service<F, R>(&self, callback: F) where F: FnMut(Result<R, i32>) {
   |                         - this type parameter
11 |         let r = self.get_instances(13);
12 |         callback(r);
   |         -------- ^ expected `Result<R, i32>`, found `Result<(Vec<i32>, u64), i32>`
   |         |
   |         arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<R, _>`
              found enum `Result<(Vec<i32>, u64), _>`
note: callable defined here
  --> src/test.rs:10:57
   |
10 |     fn watch_service<F, R>(&self, callback: F) where F: FnMut(Result<R, i32>) {
   |                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

my code here :

```
use std::error::Error;

pub trait Watch {
    fn watch_service<F, R>(&self, _: F) where F: FnMut(Result<R, i32>) ;
}

pub struct Client {}

impl Watch for Client {
    fn watch_service<F, R>(&self, callback: F) where F: FnMut(Result<R, i32>) {
        let r = self.get_instances(13);
        callback(r);
    }
}

impl Client {
    fn get_instances(&self, ws : i32) -> Result<(Vec<i32>, u64), i32> {
        Ok((vec![1], 0))
    }
}

#[test]
fn watch_service_test() {
    let client = Client{};
    client.watch_service(|r| {
        match r {
            Ok((services, _)) => {
                assert_eq!(services, vec![1]);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("err: {}", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify `R` as a unrestrained generic, that means that the caller of the method can choose any type they want (`File`, `TcpStream`, `String`, `&str`, ...) for it.
There is no way for the compiler to magically match all of the possible types with the `(Vec<i32>, u32)` you tried to give it, Rust is strictly typed after all.

Since you specifically ask that the signature of `watch_service` isn't changed the only solutions are to

- change `get_instances` to return some generic type:

  ```rust
      fn get_instances<R>(&self, ws: i32) -> Result<R, i32> {
          Err(0)
      }
  ```

  Of course there is no way to generate an arbitrary type so the only values we can return are all `Err` with any valid `i32` inside.
- Or to change the type returned into `Result<R, i32>`, again we have no way to create a `R` so the only thing we can give is an `Err`

  ```rust
      fn watch_service<F, R>(&self, callback: F) where F: FnMut(Result<R, i32>) {
          let r = self.get_instances(13).and_then(|_| Err(0));
          callback(r);
      }
  ```

---

That is most definitely not what you want though since it's pretty useless.

You may want to consider to change the signature of `watch_service` after all, the most permissive I can think of is to restrict `R` to types that `(Vec<i32>, u64)` can be turned into:

```rust
fn watch_service<F, R>(&self, callback: F)
where
    R: TryFrom<(Vec<i32>, u64)>,
    F: FnMut(Result<R, i32>),
{
    let r = self
        .get_instances(13)
        .and_then(|v| R::try_from(v).map_err(|_| 0 /* any i32 */));
    callback(r);
}
```

another way woud be to straight up require the callback to deal with the `(Vec<i32>, u64)` itself:

```rust
fn watch_service<F>(&self, callback: F) where F: FnMut(Result<(Vec<i32>, u64), i32>) {
    let r = self.get_instances(13);
    callback(r);
}
```

Comment: I want the FnMut can receive arbitrary type，so what I want is completely wrong ？   it must have some type？

Comment: Yes it's impossible for `callback` to take an arbitrary type determined by the caller and still have it take a specific type `(Vec<i32>, u32)` at the same time.

Comment: but the some innternal fn such as  .map fn can receive arbitrary type，whats the defrrence？

Comment: It's not trying to pass data with a specific type to it.

Comment: One of the problems here is that `self.get_instances(i32)` returns 1 type of thing only.  So whatever you pass in must accept that.  If it can return multiple _types_ then they all need to be related somehow, be it different variants of an enum, or all convertable to the same thing.  `map` works because it changes its behavior based on its inputs _strictly_.  You have an input, and something "stateful" here, "competing".  I know that's not a perfect explanation, but @cafce25 is doing well, and hopefully between the two you can see the problem with your approach.

Comment: if I change the signature of watch_service, but not directly call callback(r);  I want use r for some logic, how to do?     such as ,  if r.0 == xx { // todo} , and then callback(r).      right now, r is a generic type

Comment: I must define a new trait for R,  and define a fn to get the real result to use ?